# Create a Java Program to find the maximum between two numbers. Using the switch statement

Tags: java

Can someone explain how the if method works because I don't understand this code? I understand the if statement part but not the z+=0, z+=1 part because this is not my code.

```
    int x,y,z = 0;
    
    System.out.println("Input two numbers: ");
    x=sc.nextInt();
    y =sc.nextInt();
    
    if (x>y) {
        z+=0;
    }else if (y>x) {
        z+=1;
    }
    
    switch(z) {
        case 0: System.out.print(x + " is greater than " + y +".");
            break;
        case 1: System.out.print(y + " is greater than " + x +".");
            break;
        default:    System.out.print("Both are equal.");
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, this is a really convoluted, confusing and un-idiomatic way of checking whether a number is bigger than another. So, in case you're wondering, don't code like this when you'll write your own code.

Comment: Hello, sir. Could you please show me a better way to write this code for reference purposes?

Comment: Just put the first two `System.out.println`s inside the `if/else if` bodies, in place of `z+=0` and `z+=1` respectively. Also I just noticed the logic is wrong, because the `default` clause will never trigger, since `z` will stay 0 both if `x > y` and if `x == y`. So put the third `println` in an `else` clause instead. At that point you can get rid of `z`.

Comment: So you're saying that switch case can't be used if theres an if statement?

Comment: No, I'm saying it's redundant in this case. FWIW [this](https://pastebin.com/tU5vLKDz) is how I would write that program.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir, for your time; I truly appreciate it. I hope you will be able to assist me in the future with similar problems, as I am terrible at logic.

Answer (score 1):

- `z += 1` is the same thing as `z = z + 1`
- `z += 0` is the same thing as `z = z + 0`

so if `x > y` then z will have the value `0`
and if `x < y` then z will have the value `1`

Answer (score 0):

In this code, `z` is simply a count of the number of times `y` was larger than `x`. The `z+=1;` is just an increment - it's a shorthand notation for `z = z + 1`, so all it does is take `z` and increase its value by 1 (this increment is so common that many languages have included the `+=` shorthand notation for it). The `z+=0;` things is superfluous, it simply leaves `z` unchanged.

Answer (score -1):

```
z += x;
```

can also be written as:

```
z = z + x;
```

Assuming that `int z = 3;`

```
z += 0;
```

is pointless and will result in `z = 3`

```
z += 1;
```

will result in `z = 4`